# How to work with two repositories on the same data but in different networks (that can't be connected)?

Tags: git, multiple-repositories

Our team has to work with several xtest-files. To avoid conflicts and to have a history we want to use git. The problem is the following:

- From Monday till Thursday **most but not all** people will work inside network A with some desktop PCs.
- From Friday to Sunday **most but not all** people will work inside network B with their laptops
- For security reasons there's no possibility to directly connect network A and B, exchanging data is only possible with an USB flash drive.
- It is vital that the history of changes to the project is preserved.

After making some research and reading several answers (e.g. [Two identical git repositories](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5452444/two-identical-git-repositories)) I have the following plan to fulfil our requirements, but I'm not 200% sure if it will work out (or if it can be done easier) and I'd like to have some feedback from you:

- We start with a bare repository on a server on network A. Everbody clones this repository on their desktop PCs and works with it (pulling from and pushing to the repository on the server in network A) on one master branch.
- On the first Thursday one guy (let us call him git-admin) makes a new bare repository on his local desktop PC in network A, adds it as a new remote of the repository from network A and pushes all data to this local bare repository
- The git admin then puts this bare repository on his usb flash drive and copies it on a server in network B. Now everybody working in network B with their laptops clones this repository and pulls to / pushs from it

So gar so good, but now we have two central repositories and it may happen that both in network A and B people are working on it. Thus it is vital to merge them at least once a week to keep them close. The history has to be preserved on both repositories! This is were I think it becomes a bit tricky:

- Every Monday, the git admin pulls one last time from the repository in network B, starts a new bare repository on his laptop, adds it as a new remote of his repository of network B and pushes all data to this local bare repository on his laptop.
- He then puts this bare repository on his usb flash drive and copies it on his desktop pc in network A. Then at first he pulls from the central repository in network A to be up to date. Afterwars he adds the bare repository form network B as a new remote of his repository cloned from network A, pulls from it, solves all conflicts and pushes to both the origin remote repository in network A and the local bare repository that was copied from network B.
- Now the central repository in network A is up to date. He then takes the bare repository, puts it on his usb flash drive again, puts it on his laptop in network B, adds it as a new remote for the network B repository, pulls, merges and pushes to the central repository in network B.

This process will be repeated every monday and thursday (the other way round). Any suggestions to make it easier or is this the way to go? I'm not sure if it's necessary to work with the bare repositories and if it would be possible to just copy the normal up to date local repositories of the git-admin to the respective network and add the central repositories of network A and B as new remote (depending on which he is working in) and pushing and pulling from it.

Sorry for the wall of text and thank you for you help!

Answer (score 0):

Two new bare-repos every week? OMG, **no**!

One repo with two remotes (for A and B locations) and pull|push cycle, transferred between locations.

And in pure DVCS-style *each* Dev can have such own "briefcase" (and dev's local repos have two remotes - Location and Briefcase